# How do I disable a Github check for Google Cloud Build

Tags: github, google-cloud-build

I've installed the Google Cloud Build app from Github Marketplace, and enabled it on several repositories, only to discover that enabling access for those repositories automatically starts running the Google Cloud Build "check" after every PR or push to a PR.  Since some of those repositories are not actually ready for Google Cloud build, I needed to turn off the checks... I used the URL [mentioned in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/run-builds-on-github#connecting_additional_repositories) to get to the page where you can select which repositories should be connected to your GCP project, and unchecked a bunch of them... this disconnected them from the project, but, surprisingly, did not disable the Github checks!  So now, there are Github checks on several repositories that just result in an error because they're not connected to any projects in Cloud Build.

Surely, it is not an uncommon use case to need a way to "disable Checks" on a per-repository basis - is there any way to do that?

(If not, consider it a requested feature if there are any Google Engineers reading!) ;)

I did talk to chat support, and the only way we could figure out to remove the checks would be to uninstall Google Cloud Build completely from the entire organization, which I don't want to do because we *do* have some setup that I want to keep, and I don't know how much of that configuration would have to be redone if I uninstalled it completely.

Here is a screenshot of the broken check that I can't disable:

[image: GitHub PR with broken Google Cloud Build check]

Comment: How did you eventually solve this?

Comment: I started ignoring the cloudbuild checks... ;)  Which is to say, I have not solved it, but I believe @oreoluwa's answer (Remove the webhook from the repo) should work if you actually have no cloudbuild triggers for the repo (in my case I now have some custom ones I *do* want to use, but I want to disable the github default check showing up on Github, which I haven't figured out how to do)

Comment: I found a ticket on this since august, but no followup it was simply closed:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/541

Comment: There's an issue on the google issue tracker as well: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/138896013

Answer (score 4):

I think there are 2 steps to disable CloudBuild, 
 1. Disable on CloudBuild itself. For some time I kept seeing 2 builds per push made, but disabling a trigger on CloudBuild helped fix that.
 2. On Github, you can configure the Cloudbuild app to monitor a specific repo on the organization level setting.
[image]
 3. If you feel a lot adventurous though and it's not solved, on the project level setting, you could delete the `Webhooks` integration for cloudbuild, as that's what Github notifies of each build.[image]

Answer (score 4):

It can be found within GH App installations:
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcb-github-registration

Select the GH account used for your link between Cloud Build and GH, then the GCP project you want to edit.
Here connected repositories can be edited, and in the second step (Trigger settings), the "Default GitHub Checks" can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can also goto settings of your repository and click installations inside settings.
And then remove Google cloud build from Installed apps and authorized github apps.

Comment: There's no "Installations" in a repo's settings - I assume you meant "Integrations 
 & services".  Note in the original post that I mentioned I do not want to uninstall Google Cloud Build completely from the entire organization.  And using the Google Cloud Build Configuration page inside Github to remove access from certain repositories doesn't actually seem to stop the builds from firing, just makes them fail.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Build Triggers are still in beta, and have gone through several updates since this question was posted, but it now appears that the "Github Default Checks" are no longer hidden from management.  They are now explicitly offered (but not automatically created) when connecting a repo, and you can finally view and disable (or delete) individual "Github Default Checks" on the trigger management page: https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/triggers

[image]

I'll leave this as unanswered, because I'm uncertain this is how it is working for everyone, or that this answer will remain true, but if it works for you, feel free to vote up the answer!

Answer (score 0):

To link **GCP Project** to the **Github** repository, create a trigger by clicking on `resolve` link, besides **Action Required** and then **disable** the same. For me this procedure worked out.