# How do I Cancel Github Check Queue for GCP Cloud Build?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, google-cloud-build

I was experimenting with cloud build in Github. Im not sure why but the github check keeps getting hung up in the queue and it doesnt seem to ever timeout. I have no way of canceling it.

[image]

I have already:

- Closed the PR
- Disabled then deleted the trigger
- Disabled the cloud build api
- Removed the cloud build integration from github settings
- Removed any of the protected branch setting for checks

I'm not sure what to do next. I dont think I will be charged from GCP as there is no activity coming from the cloud build api logs. Perhaps there will be a charge from Github?
Does anyone know how to cancel this check or at what point it will finally timeout?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable a Github check for Google Cloud Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57185996/how-do-i-disable-a-github-check-for-google-cloud-build)

Comment: No but thanks for looking. I had seen this one bit some of the answers must be dated. Ultimately I'm still able to merge the PR --  but just not sure if its costing any money being stuck in a queue forever. Hopefully it will time out eventually, as of now its still going over 24 hours.

Comment: Your Cloud build is working fine. So its definitely not a GCP issue. There has been a couple of incidents reported in GitHub - In March- April there was an incident for GitHub Actions, which has been resolved now. There was a recent incident reported on May 11, (the same day you posted this question) on Pull requests and Webhooks. They are undergoing maintainance activity right now. So if you have any issues, it's better you contact [GitHub support](https://support.github.com/request) or open a new issue in Github. Here is the [status dashboard link](https://www.githubstatus.com/history)